# Getting the contents of the Shopping Cart

Tags: magento2

With PHP code I want to get at the contents of the shopping cart in Magento 2.

Here is my code:

```
/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart */
$items = $block->getItems();
foreach( $items as $xx ){
    var_dump($xx->getSku());
    var_dump($xx->getQty());
    var_dump($xx->getName());
    $opts = $xx->getOptions();
}
```

Using this code I can get at the SKU, the Quantity and the Name of the items in the shopping cart.

However I need to also get at the configurable options (I need to know the colour and size of the items in the shopping cart).

Can anyone help me get at this information? I believe it is in `$opts`, but I cant figure out how to get the information out of there.

Answer (score 1):

`Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::getOptions()` return as array of object of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Option`

you can try:

```
foreach( $opts as $opt ){
    var_dump($opt->getValue());
}
```

Comment: @jimmery if this worked for you, please accept the answer.